# How to reduce time gridding and interpolating 3D data using Python?

Tags: python, grid, interpolation

I have a bathymetry data that I need to plot on Python using a grid of a defined resolution, and right now I am currently doing so using a series of for loops and functions, but as the data size increases, so does the processing time, up to the point where it's simply taking too long.

Here is a sample data set (filled with ones just to make everything easier) consisting of just 3 rows (the datasets than I am trying to use has over 20.000 rows):

```
data = np.ones((3,10))
```

Each of those data points has an X and Y coordinate value, it depends on the position and heading of the boat.

```
X = np.asarray((np.linspace(0,9, num=10), np.linspace(0,8, num=10), np.linspace(0,6, num=10)))
Y = np.asarray((np.ones((10)), np.linspace(3,4, num=10), np.linspace(2,8, num=10)))
```

Now, for creating the grid I take the minimum X and Y coordinates, divide it by the resolution I want it to have, add a little padding and create a matrix full of zeros with those dimensions, later to be filled with the data point values, as such:

```
res_x = 0.5
res_y = 0.5
width = np.arange(np.min(X)-5, np.max(X)+5, res_x)
height = np.arange(np.min(Y)-5, np.max(Y)+5, res_y)
grid = np.zeros((len(height),len(width)))
```

Now, for placing the data points at their correct location on the new grid, I use the following:

```
def take_closest(myList, myNumber, length):
    """
    Assumes myList is sorted. Returns closest value to myNumber.

    If two numbers are equally close, return the smallest number.
    """
    pos = [bisect_left(myList, myNumber[i]) for i in range(length)]
    position = np.zeros_like(pos)
    for i in range(length):
        if pos[i] == 0:
            position[i] = 0
        if pos[i] == len(myList):
            position[i] = len(myList)-1
        else:
            before = myList[pos[i]-1]
            after = myList[pos[i]]
            if after - myNumber[i] < myNumber[i] - before:
                position[i] = pos[i]
            else:
                position[i] = pos[i]-1
    return position

for a in range(data.shape[0]):
        id_x = take_closest(width, X[a,:], data.shape[1])
        id_y = len(height) - take_closest(height, Y[a,:], data.shape[1])
        grid[id_y, id_x] = data[a,:]
```

Now, as you can imagine, because of the use of those for loops it can take a long time to correctly locate all the data points within the grid. The other issue that I have is that when you do plot the data, you get the following:
[Plotted data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9NRu.png)

Where there is a gap of values between each line due to the nature of the course the ship is following, and I want to fill that gap interpolating between the closest values but without exceeding the inner and outer "limits" of the data. These limits are visualize defined by the orange lines draw in the following pic:
[Limits of the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BoVjC.png)

In this particular case that doesnt seem to be a problem but if the ship where to do a 180° turn, then I wouldn't want any interpolation to be done in the gap created by that curvature. For example, if the ship where to follow a path like this:
[Hypothetical escenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmDCd.png)

Where the black line indicate the trajectory, the yellow line the outer limit of the data and the red one the inner limit, I wouldn't want any interpolation to be done in the gap between the red lines, just on any existing gap between the red and yellow lines.

I'd appreciate any help in how to improve my code since, as you can see, I am no expert.

Edit: Typos